# JQuery Plugin in ASP.NET Web Site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have an ASP.NET web site and I need to make a number of asp.net dropdownlist controls searchable (across a number of pages). I am using the jQuery Searchable DropDown Plugin and it works fine on one of the pages I have tested it on. My question is as follows, Should I be able to reference the plugin on the site.master and expect it to be referenced in all pages or do I have to reference it on all pages that I want to use it on?

If I have to add a reference to the plugin on each page then that is fine but if I can just add it in one place then obviously that is better. I have tried it and it didn't work for me but maybe it should work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If two pages of onehundred use the plugin, I'd say let those two pages reference it. If 98 pages of onehundred use it, let the master page reference it. Try to load as few libraries as possible to keep your site quick.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. It's 3 of 30 approximately so I will probably just add it to the pages it's needed in. Thanks again

Comment: If I had time and no deadlines, I'd probably spend an unneccesarry amount of hours happily writing some neat code which adds the library on demand, like a property of the MasterPage the Pages could set to true.

Comment: Thanks again for all the answers. I ended up referencing the plugin in each of the 3 pages I needed it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have multiple pages that have master page better way is you place jquery searchable dropdown in master page for use in all pages Inherited this masterPage.
otherwise if you have pages in various category and each category have separated masterPage you can place dropDown in each master page.
in last state you can place dropDown in each page.